# Python: how to create 3 single channel images

Tags: image, python-2.7, rgb

I want to create a 3 single channel images, red, green and blue with random scatters.

So far I manage to create one color images, but it is in RGB format.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image


### blue
cells = np.random.RandomState(400)
x = cells.randn(10)
y = cells.randn(10)
colors = "blue"
sizes = 250 * cells.rand(200)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, s=sizes, alpha=0.7, cmap='viridis')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I want to use the single files and combinations to test an image- analysis tool for object detection.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By saving as monochromatic (B&W)? If you are using TIFF format, GDAL is a frequent tool (library or command line) to extract and manipulate channels.

Comment: ok. I am looking into it and update later

Comment: after some more research I realized I did not think of how white is interpreted in RGB, I use black background now and the channels correspond to what I exspectd